# jQuery Accordion - Open section on new page

Tags: html, wordpress, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to figure out how to open a section within a jQuery accordion based on the anchor tag clicked from a different page, but can't quite figure it out. I'd like to have it so that the user clicks a link on [one page](http://lindseybakermedia.com/design/GPI/agenda/), which opens a [second page](http://lindseybakermedia.com/design/GPI/speaker-bios/) and takes the user directly to an open section, based on the link they clicked. Any thoughts how to get this working as such? The code below is how I have it set up at the moment - I should mention that it is a WordPress site so the HTML isn't pretty.

Page One HTML:

```
<a href="http://lindseybakermedia.com/design/GPI/speaker-bios/#welcoming-remarks">Welcoming Remarks</a>
<a href="http://lindseybakermedia.com/design/GPI/speaker-bios/#keynote-remarks">Keynote Session</a>
```

Page Two HTML:

```
<div class="vc_col-sm-12 wpb_column vc_column_container ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <div class="wpb_accordion wpb_content_element  not-column-inherit" data-collapsible="" data-vc-disable-keydown="false" data-active-tab="false">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper wpb_accordion_wrapper ui-accordion">
                <div class="wpb_accordion_section group">
                    <h3 class="wpb_accordion_header ui-accordion-header"><a href="#welcoming-remarks">Welcoming Remarks</a></h3>
                    <div class="wpb_accordion_content ui-accordion-content vc_clearfix">
                        <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
                            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                                <p>Content</p>
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="wpb_accordion_section group">
                    <h3 class="wpb_accordion_header ui-accordion-header"><a href="#keynote-remarks">Keynote Remarks</a></h3>
                    <div class="wpb_accordion_content ui-accordion-content vc_clearfix">
                        <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
                            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                                <p>Content</p>
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use below HTML and JavaScript code on Page Two:

```
JavaScript Code:
<script type="text/javascript">
var param = document.URL.split('#')[1];  
if(param == 'content1')
{
    var content = '.content1';
}
else if(param == 'content2')
{
    var content = '.content2';
}           
$("#accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    header: "h3",
    active: $('#accordion h3').index($(content)),
    heightStyle: "content"
});
});
</script>

HTML Code:

    <div id="accordion">
 <div class="vc_col-sm-12 wpb_column vc_column_container ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <div class="wpb_accordion wpb_content_element  not-column-inherit" data-collapsible="" data-vc-disable-keydown="false" data-active-tab="false">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper wpb_accordion_wrapper ui-accordion">
                <div class="wpb_accordion_section group">
                    <h3 class="wpb_accordion_header ui-accordion-header content1"><a href="#welcoming-remarks">Welcoming Remarks</a></h3>
                    <div class="wpb_accordion_content ui-accordion-content vc_clearfix">
                        <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
                            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                                <p>Content</p>
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="wpb_accordion_section group">
                    <h3 class="wpb_accordion_header ui-accordion-header content2"><a href="#keynote-remarks">Keynote Remarks</a></h3>
                    <div class="wpb_accordion_content ui-accordion-content vc_clearfix">
                        <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
                            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                                <p>Content</p>
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
</div>
```